# read access violation variable

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-c++

When i'm using `char* pilih(char teks[])` in the `int main()` function, it's working. But when I used this function in the new function, it said read access violation. Please help me

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAXARR 1000
char *hilangkan(char[]);
char *pilih(char[]);
char *loadFile(FILE *sumber);

int main(){
    FILE *sumber;
    sumber=fopen("kumpulan.txt","r");
    char *teks=loadFile(sumber);
    char *pilihan=pilih(teks);
    printf("%s",pilihan);
    printf("%s",hilangkan(pilihan));
}

char *hilangkan(char teks[]){
    char *penghilangan;
    strcpy(penghilangan,teks);
    int y=strlen(penghilangan);
    srand(time(NULL));
    int c=48;
    for(int i=0;i<y;i++){
        int hilang=rand()%y+1;
        penghilangan[hilang]='_';
    }
    return penghilangan;
}
char *loadFile(FILE *sumber){
    char *teks;
    if (sumber == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR!!!");
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
    char h;
    int count=0;
    while (h = fgetc(sumber) != EOF) { 
        teks[count] = h; 
        count++;
    }
    fclose(sumber);
    return teks;
}
char *pilih(char teks[]){
    char *hasil;
    srand(time(NULL));
    int w = rand() % 47 + 1;
    char cek[3];
    itoa(w, cek, 10);
    char *c=strstr(teks, cek);
    int lokasi = c - teks + 1;
    int pan = strlen(cek);
    int i;
    if (pan == 2)i = -1;
    else i = 0;
    while (teks[lokasi]!='\n') {
        hasil[i] = teks[lokasi];
        i++;
        lokasi++;
    }
    hasil[i] = NULL;
    return hasil;
}
```

On `while(teks[lokasi]!='\n')` it says read violation access. `teks` was `0x1110113`

Comment: Have you tried stepping through with a debugger?

Comment: What is the argument passed to `pilih()` function? Do you know `strstr()` can return `NULL` pointer.

Comment: Can you try to format that a bit? It is really hard to read your code.

Comment: @Tobi yes but it's says same

Comment: @H.S.sorry i don't know what you mean, i'm still learning

Comment: @JiaHao Xu Done

Comment: @CahyoPrastyawan What is the value of `teks`? Can you show minimal complete verifiable program.

Comment: @H.S. teks is a string. okay i will upload the source code

Comment: @CahyoPrastyawan links are highly discouraged. Please edit your question and paste the whole program.

Comment: @H.S. okay, i'm sorry, still new

Comment: You are returning the local variable from your function `pilih()`.

Answer (score 0):

Links are highly discouraged and expectation from you is that, you should post the whole program in your question.
From the part of code that you have posted and the error information shared, it seems that the argument passed to `pilih()` function is not valid which in turn makes `teks` pointer pointing to some invalid memory. Actual cause of problem can only be given after looking at minimal, complete and verifiable program depicting the problematic behavior.
One confirm problem in your `pilih()` function is that you are returning a local variable `hasil` from it. The scope and life of local variable `hasil` is limited to `pilih()` function and it is no more valid once `pilih()` function exits.

Also, this statement

```
hasil[i] = NULL;
```

is not correct. Variable `hasil` is array of `char` and `hasil[i]` is a character at index `i`. You are assigning `NULL` to it which is not valid. I think you wanted to do this:

```
hasil[i] = '\0';
```

---

EDIT:

The full code has been posted in the question. Hence editing my answer and pointing out the problems in the OP's code.

There are several issues in your code. If you are using `gcc` compiler, try compiling your code with "-Wall -Wextra" options and check the warnings messages given by the compiler.

In the function `loadFile()`, look at this statement:

```
while (h = fgetc(sumber) != EOF) {
```

First of all, the return type of `fgetc()` function is `int` and not `char` *[the `fgetc()` return type is `int` to accommodate for the special value `EOF`]*. In the operator precedence table, the operator `!=` comes before `=`, so you will not get the read character assigned to `h` but the result of `fgetc(sumber) != EOF` will be assigned to `h`. This should be

```
while ((h = fgetc(sumber)) != EOF) {  // check the parenthesis added
       ^                 ^
```

In this statement:

```
teks[count] = h;
```

You are accessing a pointer which is not initialized. **Any variable which is not initialized has indeterminate value and same is true for pointers.** They can point to any random indeterminate address. There is no default behavior. Only behavior is indeterminate and **using indeterminate values results in Undefined behavior**.

You should allocate memory to `teks` before using it, like this:

```
teks = malloc(100 * sizeof (char)); //this will allocate memory for 100 characters.
if (teks == NULL)
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

Looks like you want to store the whole file content in `teks`. Make sure to allocate enough memory to `teks` and if you are not sure about the size of memory required then `realloc` is your friend.

Also, after `while` loop, you should add the terminating null character at the end of the content stored in `teks`, like this:

```
teks[count] = '\0';
```

The same error of accessing uninitialized pointer exists in `hilangkan()` and `pilih()` function. Check the variable `penghilangan` and `hasil` respectively.

`strstr()` can return `NULL` pointer. You should add check for it:

```
char *c=strstr(teks, cek);
if (c == NULL)
   return NULL; // Or whatever the way you want to handle this case
                // but you should not use c
```

You should check the parameter value before using it in every function. If it is pointer, check whether it is `NULL` or not. If it is not `NULL` then only use it.

Also, make sure to `free` the dynamically allocated memory once you are done with it.

I don't what exactly you are trying to do but somewhere I feel that there is lot of scope of improvements in your code.

Hope this help.

Comment: so what i suppose to do for variable teks? sorry i'm still don't get it

Comment: I can't tell anything until you show minimal, complete and verifiable code in the question.